# converting java projects to c# with visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, java, visual-studio-2010

i remember that previous versions of visual studio contained a converter, that automatically attempt to convert java projects to the corresponding c# code.

however in visual studio 2010 beta 2 i cant find this anymore?

has it been removed?

thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Java Language Conversion Assistant has been [removed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6t6bsdk.aspx) from Visual Studio 2008 and future versions. You have few options:

- Install VS 2003/2005 and run the assistant
- Purchase a commercial [solution](http://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/Product_Details/Java_to_VB_and_CSharp_Converter_Details.html)
- Do the conversion by [hand](http://www.25hoursaday.com/CsharpVsJava.html)
- Use [ikvmc](http://www.ikvm.net/userguide/ikvmc.html) to compile jar files into managed .NET assemblies (personally I've done this with success)

Comment: Note that IKVM appears to have stopped being developed in 2012. Therefore it only supports up to Java class version 51 (Java 1.7). Just make sure you compile your Java code with at most 1.7. Otherwise you'll get error messages like: warning IKVMC0108: Not a class file "X.class", including it as resource
    (class format error "52.0")

Answer (score 2):

I think that was visual studio 2005 , as far as i know it doesn't exist on 2008 or 2010